# Open New Window By Clicking A Button Using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-2

In my site I want to open a new window with a url .My code after an ajax call is :

```
window.open("example url");
```

There have a button.When i clicked on this button an ajax function will work the result of the ajax function have the `example url`.When it get url i want to open the url with new tab  window.

When iam using the above code nothing will happen.
Whats wrong in my code?
This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/get_url/",
success: function(msg){
window.open(msg);
}  
});
```

The `msg` have the url.It is a codeigniter application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the syntax, it's: `open (URL, windowName[, windowFeatures])`. The way I read this windowName ist not optional. Example:

```
window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'Stackoverflow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Popup blockers tend to block windows that are opened other then in response to a user event (like a click). This is almost certainly what is tripping you up.

Open the window directly and use an HTTP redirect to get to the URL you want.

(Better yet, don't use popups).